# How to have requirements in a getline?

Tags: c++

I'm making a type of registry for a class in C++.
I have to have a part where it asks you for your first name and last name. i'm using getline and is there a way to specificate that the input must have a space so I know that they input both names?
Also same thing I need a three digit number but in the cin i'm using you can put a one digit number all the way to a infinite digit number. How do I write it to make the input only be valid with three digits?

Comment: Read the input into a string first, do whatever checks you want to make sure it's valid, and then parse it to another type of necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `std::string` and check its characters in a loop which abide by your conditions.

```cpp
std::string s;
getline(std::cin,s);
```

Use pre-defined functions such as `isalpha`, `isspace` and `isdigit` to make character comparisons easier.

Check if it contains a name following the string has only alphabets and spaces:

```cpp
int count=0, spaces=0, alphabets=0;
for(int i = 0; i < std::strlen(s); i++)
{ 
  if(isalpha(s[i]))
     { count++; alphabets++;
     }
  else if(isspace(s[i]))
     { count++; spaces++;
     }
  else
     {
       std::cout<<"Invalid";
       break; 
     }
}
if(std::strlen(s)==count && spaces!=0 && alphabets!=0)
  // Valid (do what you want)
```

Check validity for input string being of 3 digits:

```cpp
int c=0;
for(int i = 0; i < std::strlen(s); i++) 
{ 
   if(isdigit(s[i]) 
      c++;
   else 
   { 
      std::cout<<"Invalid";
      break; 
   }
}
if(std::strlen(s)==c && s.size()==3) 
  std::cout<<"Valid";
```

Comment: @Giovanni Rivera Consider accepting an answer if it helps! Also if you have any questions, feel free to ask.